# For Shopify, I'm conflicted between learning PHP or Ruby

Tags: php, ruby, shopify

I'm not sure how to phrase this question that won't get me to hate from you guys but I'm giving it a go. I'm aware of the basic syntax and logic of programming like if statement, variable, type of strings, etc (purely basic) though I'm a little more familiar with PHP.

Now I wanna learn Shopify development, though they don't have direct support for PHP but one can build Shopify apps on Laravel too (so I've heard).

I'm very conflicted between learning either PHP or Ruby because it'll be almost all the same for me and ofcourse I don't wanna learn it just for Shopify.

Anyways, your input will be appreciated.

Comment: This is really asking for an opinion.  Picking a language is a highly subjective (and could be considered somewhat religious for some) matter that you need to evaluate yourself.  You should pick the best language for the task at hand, and don't let that choice hamper you in the future from learning more.

Comment: As @Buggabill says, this is opinion-based, and I think it's likely to be closed as such... personally, having written PHP for almost a decade, I would very, very strongly prefer Ruby. While I don't like Ruby's syntax _at all_, it's still a far more mature language in terms of its engineering.

Comment: Another reason of confliction is that while I can also code WP plugins (and other CMS) in PHP, I can't do it in Ruby but as you guys said, Ruby is a much more mature laguage. And I can understand language choice being a religious one as one really gotta be devoted to it in order to master it, that's why I wanna weigh my option before I really commit to it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really makes no difference. There. I said it. Shopify is so agnostic to the tech stack you choose, it is up to you to decide what works for you.

PHP, Ruby, Python, Javascript, heck even C# all work the same for making Shopify Apps. Your preference matters. If you feel comfortable with PHP, use it! There is zero obligation to use Ruby just because Shopify uses it.

In fact, Shopify is now so agnostic, their GraphQL based API for Apps eliminates all "my stack beats your stack" crap to nothing. These days, you can safely just focus on wiring it up to work, without offending anyone. Make an HTTPS call to an endpoint, get back data. Process it, act on it, show stuff off. Simple. No need to worry about how you do that. All scripting languages do it.

Comment: That's a rather good reply. Thanks David!

Answer (score 0):

I would choose Ruby since that is the native support for, and later PHP if that is necessary in another project.